# Delete files ending in -Copy

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer

I accidentally copied A LOT of files to the same directory, and they now all end in - Copy, like i would have a file called `song.mp3` and another one called `song - Copy.mp3`. Is there a quick and easy way to remove all the copies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click in the blank space in the address bar of File Explorer, type `cmd`, and press Enter. A command prompt window appears. Type `del "* - Copy.*"` and press Enter. That command erases (permanently!) all files whose titles end with `- Copy`.

If you're worried about transcribing the command incorrectly, you can make a copy of the whole folder first.

In the future, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo a copy operation as long as you perform no other file management operations in the intervening time.

Comment: thanks! I missed the closing quotation the first time, and I'm using Recuva to recover them all (its going to take a while, a few GB of songs). I'll test your command after its done!

Comment: @Jeffmagma The closing quotation actually doesn't matter, but the opening one certainly does. `del` should have given you a warning before erasing all files in the folder, though. Interesting.

Comment: I thought the first one was a stray quotation and i thought the prompt was normal... seems like I have quite a bit to learn about these commands