# delete files from folder and subfolders named filename - copy

Tags: windows-10, deduplication

I have had an issue with Microsoft OneDrive and now I have many files named `filename - copy`.

I found [This Post](https://superuser.com/questions/1018337/delete-files-ending-in-copy) which says to use `del "* - Copy.*"` which works, within a given directory, but not sub directories. Is there any way to make it work on all sub directories?

Comment: Adding ```/S``` after what you have should work. Typing command ```del /?``` shows you the options available.

Comment: Worked beautifully. I also appreciate the tip about the different options.
Thank you!